# IBM Watson Assistant: How to work with dates?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

I am working on a chatbot that allows users to compare their spending by 2 periods (e.g. spending in 1/1/19-2/2/19 vs spending in 1/1/20-2/2/20). We hope to detect the dates below from customer input:

1. Transaction date from (DDMMYY)
2. Transaction date to (DDMMYY)
3. Comparison date from (DDMMYY)
4. comparison date to (DDMMYY)

Some customers may say "I want to compare my spending of Jan 2019 with Feb 2020".
My questions are

1. if customer only types Jan 2019 (instead of giving me the date, month and year - 01/01/19), how can we generate the date 01/01/19 from input "Jan 2019"
2. how can we tell "transaction date from" = 01/01/19 (also for "Transaction date to", "Comparison date from" and "comparison date to"). Should I set 4 entities?

Note: we are not using a language without annotation feature.

Comment: Are you using a language with or without annotations? So, are you using annotations? Have you looked into positions for detected entities? Are you using slots and confirming questions to correct input?

Comment: I am using a language without annotations.

Have you looked into positions for detected entities? <-- could you elaborate more on this?

Are you using slots and confirming questions to correct input? <-- Not all of the information are mandatory.

Comment: See entitity properties which have "location". It can be used to process the input for better understanding https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-expression-language#expression-language-entity-props